# .NET access to uninterruptible power supply status

Tags: .net

I have a .NET C# application that is running on a PC.
Would like to be able to read UPS status and if the main power is gone, would like to take action.
I have an APC unit.
Chat told me they do not provide their API.
I am sure in data centers there must be program access to UPS status.
If anyone knows a UPS company and part that provides this access that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

APC PowerChute Personal Edition writes a log file.
I found it at: C:\Program Files (x86)\APC\PowerChute Personal Edition\PCPELog.txt
There is an item in the file "Input Voltage -->120"
I have not tested it yet but I am assuming it will read 0 when main power is out.
The file updates every four seconds.